# Getting Dependency Error during installation of google-map-react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

When i try to install install google maps packeage , i get this error every time.

````
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from google-map-react@2.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/google-map-react
npm ERR!   google-map-react@"*" from the root project```
````

Comment: Can you try "npm i google-map-react --force". Or change to use yarn. There is an upstream dependency error.

Answer (score 0):

google-map-react depends on react 16 or 17 but it seems like you are using version 18 which is why you getting that error.

You can check [package.json](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/package.json) of google-map-react

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0"
  },
```

You can use `react-google-charts` package for the same purpose which is support  the latest React version

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but this error is displaying while installing react-router-dom.

Comment: This is not an answer, please stay on-topic and provide a solution.